# How to install a package on texlive? [windows 7]

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, windows

How to install a package on windows 7?

I want to install the following packages for texlive:
graphicx
graphics
subcaption
float

also, is there a way to see a list of the packages I have installed on my device?

I'm a new windows user which converted from Ubuntu recently, please take that by account when answering

Comment: Can you start the `tex live manager` - Open the start menu and search for the application. There you should get all information you need. (The packages you listed are already part of the standard distribution).

Comment: The packages : graphicx & subcaption
are not listed!. Also I can't figure out how to install packages that i don't have using [tex live manager].

Comment: How did you install texlive? AFAIK the tex live installer installs also the tex live manager.

Comment: Just another possible source of the problem: Which version did you install? The repositories support only the most actual TeXLive version (actual 2015).

Comment: I'm not saying I don't have "tex live manager"! I have it, but i don't know how to use it to get for example "subcaption " package! 
I installed it yesterday so I guess I have texlive 2015

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please start the TeXLive manager and you should get:

[image: TexLive Manager]

- In the Status-block you could select only installed packages. (marked as 1)
- In the column "Local Rev" (marked as 2) you can see the actual version.
- The column `remote rev` will contain the actual version of the remote repository (you must first load it). If there is a higher number, then there was an update.
- In the Block Repository you can load from a remote repository. This may take some time. The status block on the bottom will show you some details. (marked as 3).

  - If there is a problem, you may try to use a different repository. Select one from the menu under `tlmgr`
- With `Update all installed` you can refresh your installation.
- With `Update` you can update the selected entries. (You could select the status `updates` and select them).
- In the block `Match` you can set a filter.

As you do it the first time, you must first update the manager. Instead `Update all installed` there should be another command (sorry, I can`t provide a screenshot yet). Just follow the instructions. After the update of the TeXLive manager you have to restart it and then you can update your packages.

If you have problems, can you please post a screenshot, so we can see what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

`tlmgr` is used for package management in TeX Live. According to [the documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#NAME), to list the packages installed, use `tlmgr info` without argument:

> With no argument, lists all packages available at the package repository, prefixing those already installed with i.

To install a package, you can use `tlmgr install <PKG>` (`<PKG>` being the package name). This will also automatically install all dependency packages by default:

> By default this also installs all packages on which the given pkgs are dependent

Answer (score 0):

for texlive-2019

to run gui texlive manager... do c:\tlshell instead of c:\tlmgr --gui

Answer (score 0):

You can manage packages graphically using `Tex Live Shell` or via command line with `tlmgr`.

As of 2023, my Tex Live installation did not have anything related in the start menu, but it was easy to run these from the command prompt (`win key` then type `cmd.exe` and `enter`). Just type `tlshell` and up pops the `Tex Live Shell`.